# Is it possible to use a prototype for this in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, prototype

If the user enters a number <= 0, then the alert will message will pop up, that works fine.  But now I want to ask the user if they enter a number > 35000.  If so, I want the alert message to pop up but I want to use a prototype to do so because I want to practice using them practically.  Am I close to being right with my code or am I way off?  I feel like I'm way off.

Thanks for taking the time to read :D

```js
     function isSalaryZeroOrLess() {
       
     var s = parseInt(document.getElementById("salary").value);
    
     if(s <= 0) {
      alert("No money");
     }
    }
    
    isSalaryZeroOrLess.prototype.greaterThan = function() {
      var userSalary = s / 12;
    
      if(userSalary > 35000) {
       alert("works!");
      }
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <title>WOMP</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="gameTime.css">
    </head>  
    <body>
     <form class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4" name="formHandler" id="handle">
      <div id="allFields">
       <div class="moveUsername">
        <h1>(All numbers inputted will be assumed that it's in dollars)</h1>
        <label for="usr">What's your annual salary?</label>
        <input type="field" class="form-control" id="salary" placeholder="What's your annual salary?" required="required"> 
       </div>
    
       <div class="ageMovement">
        <label for="usr">How much do you spend every month on bills?</label>
        <input type="field" class="form-control" id="monthlyBills" name="ageChecker" placeholder="How much do you spend every month on bills?" required="required">
       </div>
    
       <div class="emailMovement">
        <label for="usr">How much do you spend when going out?</label>
        <input type="field" class="form-control" id="goingOut" name="emailChecker" placeholder="How much do you spend when going out?" required="required"> 
       </div> 
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" onclick="isSalaryZeroOrLess()">Submit</button>
     </form>
     
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What's the problem? What goes wrong? Are errors reported?

Comment: you have problem in you html... onclick="isSalaryZeroOrLess();greaterThan()"

Comment: @Alon I removed greaterThan() but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Pointy There are no errors in the console.

Comment: @chompy what do you want it to do?

Comment: @Alon I want to use a prototype to see if the users salary is > 35000.  If so, the alert message "works!" should pop up on the browser.  But I don't want to do this with a plain old function, I want to use a prototype to make this happen.

Comment: @chompy you have to create an instance of isSalaryZeroOrLess if you want to call  to greaterThan

Comment: @Alon oh ok, how should I go about doing that?

Comment: @chompy you have to use `obj =  new isSalaryZeroOrLess();` and then `obj.greaterThen()`. you still have a problem with the s that you save local in the function you have to use this.s for it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prototypes work on objects not functions. Objects are kind of like classes in oop, you can give them fields and methods. You need to create a Finance object constructor like so,

```
function Finance(salary, fixedExpense, variableExpense)
{
      this.salary = salary;
      this.fixedExpense = fixedExpense;
      this.variableExpense = variableExpense;
      this.isSalaryZeroOrLess = function() { ...}
}

var peter = new Finance(60000, 3000, 1234);
```

or once you've created your object constructor like above:

```
Finance.Prototype.isSalaryGreaterThan = function(greaterThanValue) {...}
```

Comment: This is golden, crystal clear.  Thanks a lot, ProgrammerAdept! :)

Comment: Isn't everything in JS supposed to be an object? Even functions?